# Porque me itera este resultado este bucle?

Tags: java

```
    Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Introduce un numero!");

    String tex=entrada.nextLine();

    char[] caracteres=tex.toCharArray();

    int[] numeros=new int[caracteres.length];

    for (int i=0; i<caracteres.length; i++){

        numeros[i]=caracteres[i];

        System.out.println(caracteres[i]);

        System.out.println(numeros[i]);
    }
```

El anterior código me da como resultado:

Introduce un numero!
123

1

49

2

50

3

51

En realidad no tengo idea de porque me sale este resultado, básicamente lo que quiero es almacenar en un array de numeros enteros la entrada de el usuario, pero en otra parte del codigo me estaba dando el error de que el indice esta fuera del array, gracias de ante mano.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El motivo es sencillo:

Los caracteres '1', '2' y '3' tienen como valores ASCII 49, 50 y 51, como puedes ver [aquí](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Caracteres_imprimibles_ASCII).

Cuando le pides a Java (o C, o C++, o C#) que haga una conversión de char a int, lo que realmente hace es extender el valor interno de cada caracter a un int (generalmente un char necesita 1 byte)

Answer (score 1):

Buen día, intenta convertirlo a entero primero:

```
numeros[i] = Integer.parseInt(caracteres[i]);
```